# Setting Visual Odometry parameters for Low Frequency

Tags: navigation, odometry, kinect, frequency, fovis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have tried the mono_depth_odometer node for visual odometry using a kinect in different machines. I have seen the low processing capabilities can severely degrade the odometry.

Are there any parameters which can be modified in order to have a faster visual odometry? I have seen the list in http://docs.fovis.googlecode.com/git/group__FovisCore.html#ga113578b67d3e37bc78f1fffd8440e1ff, can those parameters be modified using "rosrun node param:=value"? Any suggestions on which parameters to modify?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103306/setting-visual-odometry-parameters-for-low-frequency/) by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, those parameters can be set through rosparam, you'll have to replace hyphens with underscores though (see http://wiki.ros.org/fovis_ros#Parameters).

I havn't played much with parameter settings. My first guess to get a higher rate would be:

- decrease `feature_window_size` (could lead to false matches)
- set `use_subpixel_refinement` to 0 (could lead to worse estimates)
- if the features in your environment are small, you could lower `max_pyramid_level` (could lead to less features)

It is difficult to tune so many parameters at once. I would suggest you try different sets of parameters and compare the output.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1